# UICollectionView Drag works in the Simulator but not in iPhone 8 Device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I am developing a custom keyboard for iOS, using Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4.  The project is 100% code based (no Storyboard) and has limited use of AutoLayout (due to performance requirements).
The keyboard includes a UICollectionView that implements a reordering functionality with Drag and Drop.

Everything works fine in the following scenarios:

**Simulator**

- Running the App in the simulator
- Running the keyboards as an App Extension in the Simulator (building the dedicated Build Target as specified in Apple's [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html)

**Device (iPhone 8, with iOS 11.2.6)**

- Running the app in the device

When running the app as App Extension and after having configured the custom keyboard in the device, everything works OK, except the Drag functionality.

- The keyboard shows that drag selection animation (using `dragPreviewParametersForItemAt`), but the drag movement **does not work**

I made sure that the `dragInteractionEnabled = true` is set (in case there is a different behavior between the device and the simulator)

I tried to debug the operation, but Xcode doesn't seem to report any particular issue in the Drag and Drop Delegates

The question is. Has anyone seen this type of issue or have any recommendation?

Rgds...  e

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Hi @SherwinZadeh.  I did not.     I would love to see if you can find something.

Comment: It turns out my issue was that I had designed the Storyboard for iPhone 8 but recently changed the storyboard to iPhone X to make adjustments for Safe Area. That broke the app for 4.7" devices. I believe this is a bug with Xcode. I tried going back to an old version of my code before my change it all worked. I don't know if this is related to your issue or not but hope it helps.

Comment: FYI @SherwinZadeh and others in the future: I just had the same problem in iOS 17.x. It turned out the Simulator doesn't RequiresOpenAccess but an actual iPhone does. Once I added that to the Info.plist then enabled it in Settings / General / Keyboard / MyKbd, dragging worked. This currently isn't documented anywhere.